# How to set editable image in MailChimp template via API

Tags: api, mailchimp

I made a template with an editable image ("Editable Content Area"), like so:

```
<img src="http://somewhere.com/foo.jpg" mc:edit="header_image">
```

When making a new campaign I can replace the image while using the MailChimp editor. But I don't seem to be able to **replace the image using the API**.

If I include the URL to the image as the section content, it seems to be ignored and the campaign is created without the new image url being set.

```
    content: {
      sections: {
        header_image: "http://somewhere/else/bar.jpg",
        header: "Our latest newsletter",
        body: "<p>My fabulous content</p>",
        ... other named mc:edit section content ...
      }
    }
```

All other editable sections (text) are being properly replaced.

*Question: How can I set the url of an `mc:edit` tagged image via the campaigns/create API?*

Comment: how did you get text replacement working? i cannot figure this out after much fiddling! I have tried `<div mc:edit="body">` but its not replaced...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately editable content areas are not supported in the MailChimp API. The editable area was made for use within their own editors.

A workaround is to just have an editable content area and to put a full image tag into it via the API.

For example;

```
content: {
  sections: {
    header_image: "<img src='http://somewhere.com/foo.jpg'>",
    header: "Our latest newsletter",
    body: "<p>My fabulous content</p>",
    ... other named mc:edit section content ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, so basically it implies building your own HTML. That's what I am doing now because of this. Thank you!